# Hoe to run the node js code in aws amplify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a React/Node app which i am trying to host on AWS amplify. first try, my app deployed but i saw some pages/buttons are not working because of node js. Then i did some search and i saw that i need to modify "amplify.yml" file to:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Getting build issues(Build time out) with the above build settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a user with **AdministratorAccess-Amplify** privileges in **IAM**.

Then it is necessary to replace line 6 of the Hands-On amplify.yml with

> npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli.

The code should now display correctly to complete Hands-On